# Angular List color change based ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `angularjs` I have two list when I click first one I will push the value into another scope and bind the value to second list. Now my requirement is when first list values which are moved to second list, I need to change the color of moved values in `list1` 
Here I attached my fiddle

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2658/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findIndex` and `ng-class` together to check if the second list contains the same item as first. If present apply css class to the first list item.

**JS**:

```
   $scope.checkColor = function(text) {
       var index = $scope.linesTwos.findIndex(x => x.text === text);
       if (index > -1) return true;
       else return false;
   }
```

**HTML**:

```
<li ng-click="Team($index,line.text)" ng-class="{'change-color':checkColor(line.text)}">{{line.text}}</li>
```

**Working Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2659/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.lines = [{
      text: 'res1'
    },
    {
      text: 'res2'
    },
    {
      text: 'res3'
    }
  ];

  $scope.linesTwos = [];
  $scope.Team = function(index, text) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.text = text;
    $scope.linesTwos.push(obj)
  }

  $scope.Team2 = function(index, text2) {

    $scope.linesTwos.splice(index, 1)
  }

$scope.containsObj = function(obj, list) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (angular.equals(list[i], obj)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};
}
```

```css
.clicked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">




  <ul ng-repeat="line in lines">
    <li ng-class="{'clicked': containsObj(line,linesTwos)}" ng-click="Team($index,line.text)">{{line.text}}</li>

  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>__________</li>

  </ul>
  <ul ng-repeat="line in linesTwos">
    <li ng-click="Team2($index,line.text)">{{line.text}}</li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to achieve it using ng-class and create a dynamic class style for pushed data please check my working example fiddle 
[JS fiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2663/)

**in HTML** nedd to do these changes

`<li ng-click="Team($index,line.text,line)" ng-class="{'pushed':line.pushed}">`

```
<li ng-click="Team2($index,line.text,line)">
```

**In css**

```
.pushed{color:red;}
```

**In Controller**

```
`$scope.Team=function(index,text,line){
  var obj={};
  obj = line;
  $scope.linesTwos.push(obj)
  line.pushed = true;
}`

`scope.Team2 = function(index,text2,line){
  $scope.linesTwos.splice(index,1)
  line.pushed = false;
}
`
```

its because angular two way binding